# Button not passing value with every click. Sometimes passes undefined sometimes the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im working with a shopping cart. I have a delete item button.

The problem I'm facing is that the `onClick` event is behaving very erratic:

The way the `button` passes the `value` is very random. **Sometimes works at the first click, and sometimes I have to click it several times to make it work**.

This is how it usually behaves:

[image: onClick]

*As you can see, the first 10 clicks no id was passed, then next click passed id 1, then once again nothing, and so on.*

My **Cart.js component**

```
render() {
    const { cartItems } = this.state;
    return (
        // some jsx and other components
                        {Object.values(cartItems).map((cartItem, i) => {
                            // console.log(cartItem.id);
                            return (
                                <tr key={i}>
                                    <td scope="row">{cartItem.name}</td>
                                    <td>{cartItem.price}</td>
                                    <td>{cartItem.quantity}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            value={cartItem.id}
                                            onClick={this.removeItem}
                                            className="btn btn-danger"
                                        >
                                            <i
                                                className="fa fa-trash"
                                                aria-hidden="true"
                                            ></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                // other jsx and components
    );
}
```

}

The `removeItem()` method:

```
removeItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.value;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: We can't know how your app works, how you fetch the ids, how you delete items, or whatsoever, you should make a reproducible example as expected: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass id/value in onClick function try this

```
onClick={()=> this.removeItem(cartItem.id)}
```

and first print `e` in `removeItem()` i think you don't need `e.target.value` try this

Comment: This won't work because you directly calling `removeItem `.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright, even though that is not the standard way of passing a value to the function on a `<button />` click.

```
    <button
      onClick={() => this.removeItem(cartItem.id)}
      className="btn btn-danger"
    >
```

and define

```
removeItem(id) {
  console.log("removeItem", id);
}
```